# Excel 2010 VBA - error : Object variable or With Block variable not set

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I have an own class (ClassFoo) with a simple property (pName), and I could not set it, because I always get error ...

```
Class Modules - ClassFoo
---
Public pName as String

Public Property Let Name(Value as String)
   pName = Value
End Property
----
Somewhere else in the ModuleX
...
Dim Foo as ClassFoo
Foo.Name = "foo" <- throws error 
Foo.pName = "foo" <- throws error
```

or

```
With Foo
.pName = "foo" <- throws error 
End With
```

I changed the class 'Instancing' from 'Private' to 'PublicNotCreatable' (back and forth)
But I still have the same error ...

Thanks for the replies in advance.

Cs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to create an instance & assign it to `Foo` so;

```
Dim Foo as ClassFoo
Set Foo = new ClassFoo
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to instantiate it I believe try

```
 Dim foo as new ClassFoo
```